# I am trying to figure out a way to streamline importing data from an access database into a .Net application

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I'm writing a fairly light-weight .Net application that queries an Access database and generates a Crystal Report based on the result-set.

The Dataset fill method is a *little* slow, but manageable.

The issue is when I load the crystal report. If the dataset being passed to Crystal is sizeable, *at all*, it takes forever to load, and the user gives up.

This is the code that sets the report dataset:

```
report.SetDataSource(largeDataSet);
```

largeDataSet has two tables. I have paired them down to the absolutely essential columns.

What ends up happening is the

```
reportViewer.Show();
```

command fires, but the ReportViewer takes minutes to actually display the report.

I am at a loss.

I appreciate your help and feedback.

Comment: There are a number of things that could be affecting performance.  You may have to be a bit more specific in you question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a DataView to first sort (effectively setting up a non-clustered index) and then filter out only the rows from each table that I needed, then I set up a new dataset and used the dataView.ToTable() method to populate the new dataset.

This set up a less costly transaction for Crystal Reports. The previously 6-10 minute report is now loading in under a minute.

```
private DataSet FilterData()
    {
        DataSet filteredData = new DataSet("FilteredData");
        DataView viewAccount = new DataView(global65DataSet.SET_ACCOUNT_TABLE);
        viewAccount.Sort = "Number ASC";
        viewAccount.RowFilter = " Number >= '" + beginningAcct+"' AND Number <= '" + endAcct + "' ";

        DataView viewTrans = new DataView(global65DataSet.SET_TRANSACTION_TABLE);
        viewTrans.Sort = "Transaction_ID ASC, DateTime ASC";
        viewTrans.RowFilter = " DateTime >= '" + beginningDate.ToShortDateString() + "' AND DateTime <= '" +
                              endDate.ToShortDateString() + "'";

        filteredData.Tables.Add(viewAccount.ToTable());
        filteredData.Tables.Add(viewTrans.ToTable());
        filteredData.Tables[0].TableName = "SET_ACCOUNT_TABLE";
        filteredData.Tables[1].TableName = "SET_TRANSACTION_TABLE";

        return filteredData;
    }
```

There's probably a better, more OO way to do this, but this works :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try a performance profiler app.
ANTS Performance Profiler is a good one.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm

Comment: Thanks, that suggestion helped me narrow in on the problem.